# Термины type deduce, track, stick, commit - что они означают?

Tags: c++

1. Подскажите что означают термины type **deduce**, **stick**, **track**, **commit**? (https://youtu.be/xnqTKD8uD64?t=3046)

Насчёт type deduce инфу нашел - определение типа впоследствии, лежит в основе auto и шаблонов. (так ведь?)

Суть остальных терминов к сожалению не понял.

2. Что происходит в `auto pb = unique_ptr<base>{ make_unique<derived>() };`? (https://youtu.be/xnqTKD8uD64?t=2952)

Правильно ли я понимаю, что это передача `make_unique<derived>` как r-value в инициализацию `unique_ptr<base>`, после чего, согласно move-семантике `unique_ptr`, владение derived-объектом передаётся `unique_ptr<base>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- deduce - да, это вывод типа. Это наверное самая главная фишка auto - позволить компилятору самому вывести тип. Больше здесь https://effective-modern-cpp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapter1.html или в известных книгах Майерсах.
- stick на несколько минут раньше https://youtu.be/xnqTKD8uD64?t=2979 рассказывается, что stick - это явное указание типа в каком то виде. Например, `auto x = type{ expr };`
- track - здесь имеется ввиду, что если код написан с массовым использованием auto, то тип у переменных все равно есть точный и компилятор за ними следит (слово track можно перевести как отслеживает) - [and the variable’s type automatically tracks other functions’ and expressions’ types unless you explicitly said otherwise.](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/). В результате, можно только в ключевых местах расставить типы, а все остальное сделает компилятор сам. Если нужно поменять тип, то это можно опять же сделать в нескольких местах, а не по всей программе.
- commit - тут видимо сокращение от "commit to a type" - явно определить тип. На [сайте у Саттера](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) оно часто употребляется в таком контексте. очень близко к **stick**. Мне нравится вот такой пример - функция [as_unsigned](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/13/gotw-93-solution-auto-variables-part-2/) которая делает так, что тип будет беззнаковым. То есть, мы "коммитимся" (как бы делаем обещания), что наш тип должен иметь такие гарантии.

> Что делает `auto pb = unique_ptr<base>{ make_unique<derived>() };`?

Здесь создается один unique_ptr, который потом передается другому. В вопросе Вы правдоподобно все написали. А вот зачем он так пишет - это интересно. Как по мне, он хочет использовать auto просто везде где это можно и в процессе рождаются вот такие монстры. В принципе это ничем не отличается от приведенного выше `auto x = type{ expr };`

Comment: Большое спасибо за понятный и развёрнутый ответ!